# How can I add {user}:{password}@ to Java URI?

Tags: java, authentication, uri

I need to use a very outdated variant of authentication for a third party server in my Java application. It looks like a subdomain:

`https://{user}:{password}@cool-domain.com/etc/etc`.

##### I know this is weird, ugly, dangerous and almost a crime.

But my question is: how can use this kind of *URI* with a simple Java URI?

I am doing this:

```
final URI myURI = URI.create("https://username:admin@cool-domain.com/etc/etc");
final HttpRequest requ = HttpRequest.newBuilder().GET().uri(myURI).build();
```

When I just log the URI based on the **sent request**:

```
HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(requ, BodyHandlers.ofString()); // which is the java.net.http.HttpClient
Helpers.logger.debug(response.request().uri().toString());
```

I am getting the exact given URI. But the server does not recognize the authorization and gives a 401. When I use the same URI als URL in a browser, the request works just fine: the response has 200 status and the content looks like I'd expect it.

So I have actually two questions:

#### 1. How can I debug what is actually happening with the URI string?

I have used *lsof* like this: `watch -n1 lsof -i TCP:80,443`.

When *lsof* catches the request, some domain name resolution has happened in the meantime and cannot see what has happened:

```
java    76953    myname   56u  IPv6 1525771      0t0  TCP myname-work:60370->ns1.server-name.com:https (ESTABLISHED)
```

(*cool-domain.com* is a server alias, so it points to *server-name.com*).

I am not familiar with networking details, but I guess that *lsof* catches a package **after some DNS lookup process**. But I need to see, what is actually sent by my Java application.

#### 2. Is it possible at all to use a form like this with Java URI:

*https://{user}:{password}@cool-domain.com/etc/etc* and how can I achieve it?

Comment: Without looking into it, my best guess that it's nothing really to do with the ```URI``` . It will probably be to do with the fact that the api you're using won't automatically produce the authorization from what I think can be got from ```URI.getUserInfo()``` You'll have to do that yourself with the api's auth mechanism

Comment: The  [auth mechanism](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/Authenticator.html)

Comment: @g00se does that also work for the new HTTP client?

Comment: When adding username and password to the URL like that, it's the same as basic authentication. That can be replaced with a header: `Authorization: Basic <username:password in base64>`

Comment: @g00se Well, like I've said: *When I use the same URI as URL in a browser, the request works just fine: the response has 200 status and the content looks like I'd expect it.* It might be the case that the problem is not related to `URI`, so I would need to debug this a little bit deeper.

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd expect a simple api to behave in the same way as a massively complex piece of software..?   But i've given you a possible way of making it do so

Comment: @g00se You are right, I should think again, because this way of authentication is designed for a PHP script (a PHP script is receiving). So I need to look in this direction. A PHP line like this should work: `file_get_contents("https://".$user.":".$pw."@cool-domain.com/Export.php);` and trying to reproduce this in Java by using a very basic client might be hybris.

Comment: In a way it doesn't matter what kind of page is at the receiving end. Basic authentication is performed at the web server level. If you put up a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I might be able to help you fix it so that it authenticates

Comment: @g00se thanks a lot! I am going to figure out a way of using an `Authenticator` and ask again after some 'research'. This will probably happen next week.

Comment: @g00se Alright, using a very simple `Authenticator` in the client works. I am overriding `getPasswordAuthentication` and add an instance of my class to the client builder. `HttpClient.newBuilder().connectTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(90 * 1000)).sslContext(sslContext).authenticator(new MyAuthenticator()).build()`. Now I need to understand, why this works.

Comment: What's the mystery? ;)

Comment: @g00se The mystery is in my lack of knowledge. I guess that the authenticator adds an `Authorization` header. But I cannot see this, when I inspect the request in the browser, which somehow manages to do the authentication. Something must happen in the browser, which I don't understand yet.